# jquery save temporarily submit & run my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have numbers of forms. Each form has is validation when you press on "send" button (function run's ONSUBMIT).  How can I store their function temporarily into  a var when you press the send button and run my validation and then (if pass OK) run their validation?

```js
jQuery('form').each(function () {
            var originalFormSubmit = jQuery(this).attr('submit');
            $(this).removeAttr('submit');
            jQuery(this).submit("myValidation()");
  });

  function myValidation(){
      // some Validation
      var ISvalid = checkInputText(); // return true or false
      if (ISvalid) {
          originalFormSubmit();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use a library like http://jqueryvalidation.org/?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

Here is a JSBin http://jsbin.com/zahiyumoki/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2015 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/pugacamafo/1/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="post" action="">

    <input type="text" id="Input1" class="form-control" / >
    <input type="text" id="Input2" class="form-control" / >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


  </form>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">
var val1 = function validateOne(){
  //simple validation

  if($('#Input1').val() !== 'ta')
    $('#Input1').addClass('error');




};

var val2 = function validateTwo(){
 //simple validation

  if($('#Input2').val() !== 'da')
     $('#Input2').addClass('error');


};

var sub = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var _this = this;


  $.each( $(':input') , function(i,v){

    $(this).trigger('change');


  });


  if( $(':input.error').length === 0 )
    _this.submit();



};


$(document).on('change','#Input1', val1 );

$(document).on('change','#Input2', val2 );

$(document).on('submit','form', sub );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I try to add addition validation to the exists.
I do not always know what there is validation.
So I have to keep in  variable the validation exists then run 
My validation and then run the validation that I kept.

Comment: @טוביהשיינפלד I'm not sure I completely understand, but if you add the ValidateMe class to all form-controls that need validation, you can check for :input.ValidateMe.error instead of :input.error

Answer (score 0):

Apologize me for being unable to comment below your post. As far as I can tell you want to neglect any submission to the server/redirected page before user has completed/filled REQUIRED inputs in your various forms.

My one suggestion would be to add your own specified '**data-**' attribute on each form tag and store the boolean statement for each form entered in the loop you mentioned above.

This solution is like :

```
<form id="form_1" name="Example 1" data-validated="false"></form>
```

Another one is to make global variables in your JS file/section specific for each form in your project.

Comment: no need to Apologize. thank for your answer.
all the form are a simple contact forms with validation when press on SUBMIT button.

Comment: You have ONE submit button in the end or MULTIPLE buttons for each form. Could be kind of you if you'd share either HTML markup or a screenshot.

Comment: All forms are separate forms with a separate submit button for each